# Ubuntu14.04 compile openjdk ERROR：FreeType version 2.3.0 or higher is required

Tags: java, compiling, openjdk

I am using Ubuntu14.04 to compile openjdk,when I run "**make sanity**" met two ERROR . This problem has been consumed for several days,how can I fix them?

```
ERROR: FreeType version  2.3.0  or higher is required. 
 make[2]: Entering directory `/home/lzw/test/openjdk/jdk/make/tools/freetypecheck'
/bin/mkdir -p /home/lzw/test/btbins
rm -f /home/lzw/test/btbins/freetype_versioncheck
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/lzw/test/openjdk/jdk/make/tools/freetypecheck'
Failed to build freetypecheck.  

ERROR: You do not have access to valid Cups header files. 
       Please check your access to 
           /usr/include/cups/cups.h 
       and/or check your value of ALT_CUPS_HEADERS_PATH, 
       CUPS is frequently pre-installed on many systems, 
       or may be downloaded from http://www.cups.org 

Exiting because of the above error(s).
```

Comment: Did you try what the error message suggests?

Comment: Thank you ! I found some sulotion like this http://askubuntu.com/questions/663810/libfreetype6-dev-depends-libfreetype6 ,but it dosn't help. I don‘t know what to do now..

Comment: 14.04 appears to provide `libfreetype6-dev` version 2.5.2: have you installed it? BTW why do you need to build openjdk?

Answer (score 2):

Even though I'm using Fedora, simply installing `cups-devel` solved the problem. Try installing the equivalent on Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install libcups2-dev
```